# Loading and calling functions in C++ from pascal DLL/SO

Tags: c++, dll, pascal

I have a compiled a library and I am trying to access the functions from c++ code. Most functions work properly, however I have some trouble with passing parameters to a function that accepts an array as argument.

The pascal function header is defined as:

```
function MyFunc( const Name  : PAnsichar; 
                 const MyArr : array of single;
                 const ArrLength : Longint;
                 var output : single
                ): Longint;
```

I can compile this function and use is properly when using pascal to load the function and call the functions in the library. Note: the library is compiled using the CDecl calling convention.

However I have trouble with loading the functions in C++.

The function is defined as:

```
typedef long (*MyFunc)(char *, float, long, float *);
```

I am able to load the dll properly and acces all the function properly, all but the one above.

```
long ArrLeng = 300;
float out;
float Arr[ArrLeng];
\\ fill the array

result = MyFunc((char *) "default", Arr[0], ArrLeng, &out);
```

I can attach the debugger to the library and check the variables read by the library. The strange thing is that the Name and ArrLeng variables are passed on properly, but the array is not passed properly.

What am I doing wrong? How should I pass the array to the library?

Comment: If `MyArr` is array, shouldn't be second argument of your function declaration be `float *`?

Comment: The C++ declaration does not match the Pascal declaration. To produce a proper translation, it is crucial to know *which* Pascal and on which OS (or OSes). I assume FreePascal. But it is well possible that they don't use the same calling convention. This depends on the OS and, again, on the Pascal being used.

Comment: Indeed I use Freepascal 3.0.0. By calling convention you mean `Stdcall` and `Cdecl `? How should I include this in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a pointer to the first element. "Array of Single" is a so called open array which is a pascal construct that also passes array boundary information.

However when used in combination with cdecl afaik it reduces to a pointer to elementtype. (single *)  At least Free Pascal does, I don't know what Delphi/Kylix does.

In doubt let pascal call it and check the resulting assembler.